# Ember-cli implementing custom serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ember.js, ember-cli

In an Ember-cli based project with a Rails 4 backend - I need to be able to save (and eventually also read) nested data.  The data model is straight forward ...

```
Survey
  name: string

Question:
  survey_id: integer
  question_type_id: integer
  text: string

Answer: 
  question_id: integer
  text: string

A Survey hasMany Questions.  Each Question hasMany Answers
```

I'm trying to figure out how write a custom Survey serializer.  Based on my research I know that I need to extend DS.JSONSerializer - but I'm not sure what to do from there.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Ember-cli comes with a generator for starting serializers. You can run it with

```
$ ember g serializer Survey
```

which produces:

```
version: 0.0.40
installing
  create app/serializers/survey.js
  create tests/unit/serializers/survey-test.js
```

Out of the box, the serializer will look like this:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
});
```

You can now customize it based on your needs. Since you haven't given any indication as to what sort of customization you're looking to do, you might want to read over [the documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html). Specifically you could check out the [section on customization](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#toc_customization).

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't work for me. I create the serializer for my model but it seems that the methods never get called when I load the model. What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Same Problem here.. `init` gets called, but `serialize` does not.